# How can I dump the result of a query into a file using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, ssms

I have a query which provides xml in a column. By

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(CAST([DATA] AS nvarchar(MAX)), 'encoding="utf-8"', '') AS XML) as mydata
```

I receive a clickable result-set. By clicking on the result I receive a tab which I can save into a file by "save ... . xml".

Is there a way to automate this process?

Comment: Thanks for all the replys. I´ve already known all the given solutions. What I´m looking for is: Every row of the results to a seperated file. In my case every XML can have more that 1000 rows. And every query can have more than 1000 resuts. So it is impossible to save that in one file and execute a satisfying post processing.

Answer (score 4):

This can also be done in SSMS by going to menu and selecting following
 `Query> Results To > results to file`

[image]
Also you can further customize the file options by clicking
 `Query> Query options`

[image]

Comment: Well, this resolves my dilemma for translation. Good explanation also for the configuration settings

Comment: Thx for your reply. This would also dump everything into one file. Also I didn´t find a working "Maximum number of characters" to display the full XML of just one data set.

Answer (score 2):

use `BCP` utility

```
bcp "select * from your_query" queryout "E:\filename.csv" -c -t , -S servername -U username -P password >FileName.log
pause
```

**Note :** This will create file in your **local machine** hard drive not in Server hard drive.

Comment: This would also dump everything to one file. But the size of the xml and the number of the results are to large

Comment: Thank for your reply

Comment: I had issues with BCP in the past.  I was unable to get images to download.  Eventually had to write code to do it.  Never did find a way to BCP images.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Sql Server Management Studio, you can output the results of your queries to an RPT file (it is just a text file) using the menu command

```
 Query -> Results To -> Results to file (CTRL+SHIFT+F)
```

and then, when you run your query, you will be prompted by a dialog to choose the folder and name for your file.

Comment: Thx for your reply. This would also dump everything into one file. This does not work in my case.

Comment: I see your comment above now. I don't know of anything in SSMS that could accomplish your goal. Perhaps using some kind of ad hoc Stored Procedure or using a custom made code in your preferred development environment.

Comment: Do you know an other tool that could accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can solve the problem using [SSMSBoost](http://www.ssmsboost.com) addin, that I develop.

There is a grid-scripting engine, that allows to select scripting granularity to "row".

You can write specialized template (using existing sample templates) that will output your data to multiple files.
Hint: you will need to write the query, that will return only 1 column with your XML data to exclude other data output into files.

Download, install, play, tell me what you think (to support@ email)